# Is there a way to reuse a struct in Vespa

Tags: vespa

Is there a way to reuse a set of fields in a Vespa Schema?

If I had a set of fields that were structs and each struct had a set of identical fields is there a way to define the identical set once and reuse it in each struct through out the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. Pretty much everything else supports inheritance but not structs. I can add it in a little while.

Comment: Done in https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/pull/19949. This will be released in 7.499 which should go out tomorrow. Then you can write struct my_struct inherits another_struct to get the shared fields defined there.